# Function not repeating in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function in `Javascript` that I need to repeat every 5 seconds.

Here is the simple code:

```
function myFunk() {
    $('body').addClass('polyonloaded');
    setTimeout(myFunk, 5000);  
}

myFunk();
```

It runs the function once, and does not repeat it anymore. What went wrong with my code?

Comment: What should be the expected behavior ? addClass is not adding multiple time the same class on an element.

Comment: Why do you need to add multiple polyonloaded class on body?

Comment: How do you know it only runs once?

Comment: @Hacketo Check the edit on the post, added codepen.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3sw224rn/ Jquery wont add the same class multiple times. Maybe that's throwing you off

Comment: @Pik_at Check the edit on the post, added codepen.

Comment: Your codepen looks totally different from your sample here. It shouldn't call multiple times in the codepen.

Comment: @Carlton, your codepen code is not the same as the code you provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add and remove the class.

Set an interval that adds the class, then set a timeout inside to wait a bit that removes it, just before the next interval.

Forked yours here: 
http://codepen.io/snlacks/pen/KwoELp

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval( function() {
    $('body').addClass('polyonloaded');
    setTimeout( function(){ 
        $('body').removeClass('polyonloaded');
  }, 4000)}, 5000 );
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code is working; try printing something:

```
function myFunk() {
   $('body').addClass('polyonloaded');
   console.log('hello');
   setTimeout(myFunk, 5000);  
}
myFunk();
```

The problem: since the added class is always the same, nothing happens: 
the class is already added; it won't be added again.

If you want to add, remove, add, remove, ... etc. use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
function myFunk() {
   $('body').toggleClass('polyonloaded');
   setTimeout(myFunk, $('body').hasClass('polyonloaded') ? 4000 : 5000);  
}
myFunk();
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working fine:

```
function myFunk() {
    console.log('running');
    setTimeout(myFunk, 1000);  
}

myFunk();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dem6u89L/